# How to use Espresso Idling Resource for network calls

Tags: android, networking, android-espresso, idle-processing

Im trying to use Espresso to test my UI. When i login into my application, i do a call to Parse API (network call) to verify the username and password. If all is well the user gets directed to a new activity. I want to test this, but i cant seems to work with the idle resource thing.

Code:

```
public class ApplicationTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<LoginActivity> {


private CountingIdlingResource fooServerIdlingResource;

public ApplicationTest() {
    super(LoginActivity.class);
}

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    injectInstrumentation(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
    getActivity();
    CountingIdlingResource countingResource = new CountingIdlingResource("FooServerCalls");
    this.fooServerIdlingResource = countingResource;
    Espresso.registerIdlingResources(countingResource);
}


public void testChangeText_sameActivity() {
    // Type text and then press the button.
    onView(withId(R.id.username))
            .perform(typeText("s@s.nl"), closeSoftKeyboard());
    onView(withId(R.id.password))
            .perform(typeText("s"), closeSoftKeyboard());

    if(performClick())
        onView(withId(R.id.main_relative_layout))
                .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    // Check that the text was changed.
}

public boolean performClick(){
    fooServerIdlingResource.increment();
    try {
        onView(withId(R.id.login)).perform(click());
        return true;
    } finally {
        fooServerIdlingResource.decrement();
    }
}


@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
public final class CountingIdlingResource implements IdlingResource {
    private static final String TAG = "CountingIdlingResource";
    private final String resourceName;
    private final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private final boolean debugCounting;

    // written from main thread, read from any thread.
    private volatile ResourceCallback resourceCallback;

    // read/written from any thread - used for debugging messages.
    private volatile long becameBusyAt = 0;
    private volatile long becameIdleAt = 0;

    /**
     * Creates a CountingIdlingResource without debug tracing.
     *
     * @param resourceName the resource name this resource should report to Espresso.
     */
    public CountingIdlingResource(String resourceName) {
        this(resourceName, false);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a CountingIdlingResource.
     *
     * @param resourceName  the resource name this resource should report to Espresso.
     * @param debugCounting if true increment & decrement calls will print trace information to logs.
     */
    public CountingIdlingResource(String resourceName, boolean debugCounting) {
        this.resourceName = checkNotNull(resourceName);
        this.debugCounting = debugCounting;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return resourceName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isIdleNow() {
        return counter.get() == 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerIdleTransitionCallback(ResourceCallback resourceCallback) {
        this.resourceCallback = resourceCallback;
    }

    /**
     * Increments the count of in-flight transactions to the resource being monitored.
     * <p/>
     * This method can be called from any thread.
     */
    public void increment() {
        int counterVal = counter.getAndIncrement();
        if (0 == counterVal) {
            becameBusyAt = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        }

        if (debugCounting) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Resource: " + resourceName + " in-use-count incremented to: " + (counterVal + 1));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Decrements the count of in-flight transactions to the resource being monitored.
     * <p/>
     * If this operation results in the counter falling below 0 - an exception is raised.
     *
     * @throws IllegalStateException if the counter is below 0.
     */
    public void decrement() {
        int counterVal = counter.decrementAndGet();

        if (counterVal == 0) {
            // we've gone from non-zero to zero. That means we're idle now! Tell espresso.
            if (null != resourceCallback) {
                resourceCallback.onTransitionToIdle();
            }
            becameIdleAt = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        }

        if (debugCounting) {
            if (counterVal == 0) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Resource: " + resourceName + " went idle! (Time spent not idle: " +
                        (becameIdleAt - becameBusyAt) + ")");
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Resource: " + resourceName + " in-use-count decremented to: " + counterVal);
            }
        }
        checkState(counterVal > -1, "Counter has been corrupted!");
    }

    /**
     * Prints the current state of this resource to the logcat at info level.
     */
    public void dumpStateToLogs() {
        StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder("Resource: ")
                .append(resourceName)
                .append(" inflight transaction count: ")
                .append(counter.get());
        if (0 == becameBusyAt) {
            Log.i(TAG, message.append(" and has never been busy!").toString());
        } else {
            message.append(" and was last busy at: ")
                    .append(becameBusyAt);
            if (0 == becameIdleAt) {
                Log.w(TAG, message.append(" AND NEVER WENT IDLE!").toString());
            } else {
                message.append(" and last went idle at: ")
                        .append(becameIdleAt);
                Log.i(TAG, message.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

The exception i get now is the following:

```
ndroid.support.test.espresso.IdlingResourceTimeoutException: Wait for [FooServerCalls] to become idle timed out
```

When i run the test, the username and password are getting filled in but the perform click is never called and i get the exception after a few seconds. How should i implement the idle resource correctly?

EDIT --

I would recommend using Calabash for Android. Calabash works similar but doesn't need you to change your app code for testing.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Like the other answer suggests, the countingIdlingResource does not really apply for your use case.

What I always do is add an interface - let's call this one `ProgressListener` - as a field of the activity / fragment that has a resource to be waited on (asynchronous background work, longer networking sessions, etc.) and a method to notify it everytime the progress is shown or dismissed.

I'm assuming you have your credentials validation logic and the call to the Parse API in the `LoginActivity`, which will then call an intent to the `MainActivity` if successful.

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ProgressListener mListener;
     
    ...    

    public interface ProgressListener {
        public void onProgressShown();          
        public void onProgressDismissed();
    }
    
    public void setProgressListener(ProgressListener progressListener) {
        mListener = progressListener;
    }

    ...

    public void onLoginButtonClicked (View view) {
        String username = mUsername.getText().toString();
        String password = mPassword.getText().toString();
        
        // validate credentials for blanks and so on

        // show progress and call parse login in background method
        showProgress();
        ParseUser.logInInBackground(username,password, new LogInCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseUser parseUser, ParseException e) {
                        dismissProgress();
                        if (e == null){
                            // Success!, continue to MainActivity via intent
                            Intent intent = new Intent (LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else {
                             // login failed dialog or similar.
                        }
                   }
               });
    }  
    
    private void showProgress() {
    // show the progress and notify the listener
    ... 
    notifyListener(mListener);
    }
    
    private void dismissProgress() {
    // hide the progress and notify the listener        
    ...
    notifyListener(mListener);
    }        

    public boolean isInProgress() {
    // return true if progress is visible 
    }

    private void notifyListener(ProgressListener listener) {
        if (listener == null){
            return;
        }
        if (isInProgress()){
            listener.onProgressShown();
        }
        else {
            listener.onProgressDismissed();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, simply implement the [IdlingResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/IdlingResource.html) class and override its methods to communicate when the resource goes from busy to idle through its [ResourceCallBack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/IdlingResource.ResourceCallback.html)

```
public class ProgressIdlingResource implements IdlingResource {

    private ResourceCallback resourceCallback;
    private LoginActivity loginActivity;
    private LoginActivity.ProgressListener progressListener;

    public ProgressIdlingResource(LoginActivity activity){
        loginActivity = activity;

        progressListener = new LoginActivity.ProgressListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressShown() {
            }
            @Override
            public void onProgressDismissed() {
                if (resourceCallback == null){
                    return ;
                }
            //Called when the resource goes from busy to idle.
            resourceCallback.onTransitionToIdle();
            }
        };

        loginActivity.setProgressListener (progressListener);
    }
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "My idling resource";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isIdleNow() {
        // the resource becomes idle when the progress has been dismissed
        return !loginActivity.isInProgress();
    }

    @Override
    public void registerIdleTransitionCallback(ResourceCallback resourceCallback) {
        this.resourceCallback = resourceCallback;
    }
}
```

Last step is to register your custom idling resource in the test's `setUp()` method:

```
Espresso.registerIdlingResources(new ProgressIdlingResource((LoginActivity) getActivity()));
```

And that's it! Now espresso will wait for your login process to complete and then continue with all the other tests.

Please let me know if I wasn't clear enough or if that is exactly what you needed.

Comment: I wIll try this out tonight !! thanks ! will get back to you :)

Comment: Good luck, It may seem like a bit of extra work, but logging was extremely helpful for me

Comment: I tried it and it worked !! i was way off with my code ! didn't aspected to implement any code in my "app" code. Its a real downside to change my app code to make my tests work. I got alot of Parse API calls. I believe my code is going to be a mess with all this ! But that was not the question, you have answered my real question. So thank you for that !

Comment: I'm glad it helped :) 
Maybe it's not the only way, but hey, not everyone writes ui tests AND handles networking at the same time. So I'm assuming it's worth it. All the best!

Comment: You can do something similar by looking for the progress view/fragment's visibility instead of adding the `isInProgress()` solely for the use of your test code.

Comment: Doesn't this cause a memory leak since your idling resource now has a strong reference to the activity?

Comment: It works great, I've used it with [otto](https://square.github.io/otto/) library, so I do not have to worry about listeners.

Comment: Nice solution but it is deprecated. The reason and workaround is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47079964/124253

Comment: Outdated solution. onTransitionToIdle is deprecated. Check here: https://www.repeato.app/espresso-wait-for-netowork-call/

Answer (score 10):

The answers above seem kind of outdated for 2020.
Nowadays don't need to create the CountingIdlingResource yourself. There is one already. You can create a singleton instance of it and access it in your activity code:

```
// CountingIdlingResourceSingleton.kt:
import androidx.test.espresso.idling.CountingIdlingResource

object CountingIdlingResourceSingleton {

    private const val RESOURCE = "GLOBAL"

    @JvmField val countingIdlingResource = CountingIdlingResource(RESOURCE)

    fun increment() {
        countingIdlingResource.increment()
    }

    fun decrement() {
        if (!countingIdlingResource.isIdleNow) {
            countingIdlingResource.decrement()
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it like this in your application code:

```
// MainActivity.kt:
start_activity_button.setOnClickListener {
    val intent = Intent(context, LoginActivity::class.java)

    CountingIdlingResourceSingleton.increment()
    // I am using a kotlin coroutine to simulate a 3 second network request:
    val job = GlobalScope.launch {
        // our network call starts
        delay(3000)
    }
    job.invokeOnCompletion {
        // our network call ended!
        CountingIdlingResourceSingleton.decrement()
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

Then register your idling resource in the test:

```
// LoginTest.kt: 
@Before
fun registerIdlingResource() {
    IdlingRegistry.getInstance().register(CountingIdlingResourceSingleton.countingIdlingResource)
}

@After
fun unregisterIdlingResource() {
    IdlingRegistry.getInstance().unregister(CountingIdlingResourceSingleton.countingIdlingResource)
}
```

You can find additional information on my blog post about [how to make espresso wait for network calls](https://www.repeato.app/espresso-wait-for-netowork-call/)

Comment: This is great, thanks! How do I wait for a real network call instead of the simulated 3 seconds delay? I'd like to get a callback from my network call when its done which also runs in a coroutine.

Comment: How do you use this in a test?

Comment: registerIdleTransitionCallback(IdlingResource.ResourceCallback resourceCallback), you can get it https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/idling/CountingIdlingResource

Comment: Do we have to add code in production just to make test wait for it?

Comment: It is a good practice to *do not have* a test code in the production code. I haven't found yet a better alternative yet, but it worth to mention it under offered solution.

Comment: Although, google team offers a different approach: *When adding idling resources into your app, we highly recommend placing the idling resource logic in the app itself and performing only the registration and unregistration operations in your tests.* https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/idling-resource

Comment: @Gleichmut In spite of their approach, I still prefer to not include test code in my Activity if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Espresso will poll the idling resource just before performing the click (or any view action). But you don't decrement your counter until *after* the click. It's a deadlock.

I don't see any quick fix here; your approach doesn't really make sense to me. A few possible alternate approaches come to mind:

- Depending on what library you use for networking, you might be able to write an idling resource which checks if there's a call in progress.
- If you show a progress indicator while the login call is in progress, you could install an IdlingResource which waits for that to disappear.
- You could wait for the next activity to be launched, or for a certain view to appear/disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to have a custom Idling resource that can examine your activity. I have created one here:

```
public class RequestIdlingResource implements IdlingResource {
    private ResourceCallback resourceCallback;
    private boolean isIdle;

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return RequestIdlingResource.class.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isIdleNow() {
        if (isIdle) return true;

        Activity activity = getCurrentActivity();
        if (activity == null) return false;

        idlingCheck(activity);

        if (isIdle) {
            resourceCallback.onTransitionToIdle();
        }
        return isIdle;
    }

    private Activity getCurrentActivity() {
        final Activity[] activity = new Activity[1];
        java.util.Collection<Activity> activities = ActivityLifecycleMonitorRegistry.getInstance().getActivitiesInStage(Stage.RESUMED);
        activity[0] = Iterables.getOnlyElement(activities);
        return activity[0];
    }

    @Override
    public void registerIdleTransitionCallback(
            ResourceCallback resourceCallback) {
        this.resourceCallback = resourceCallback;
    }

    public void idlingCheck(Activity activity)
    {
        /* 
           Look up something (view or method call) on the activity to determine if it is idle or busy

         */
    }
}
```

https://gist.github.com/clivejefferies/2c8701ef70dd8b30cc3b62a3762acdb7

I got the inspiration from here, which shows how it could be used in a test:

https://github.com/AzimoLabs/ConditionWatcher/blob/master/sample/src/androidTest/java/com/azimolabs/f1sherkk/conditionwatcherexample/IdlingResourceExampleTests.java

The good thing is that you do not have to add any test code to your implementation class.